# Changing bgcolor of Input pre and post tabs

Tags: antd

I've been looking but can't locate the key reference that enables me to update the Inputs pre/post tab.

```js
<Input
  addonAfter=".com" // <-- I want to change this bg color
  defaultValue="100"
  style={{
    width: '110px',
    backgroundColorAddonAfter: 'red' //HERE, whats the key name?
  }}
/>;
```

The pre/post tabs are the 'greyish' areas that `http:` and `.com` in them. I want to change those colors.

[image]

Comment: Any example what does pre/post tab means? Do you mean focus color?

Comment: I updated the original post with an image showing what i want to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

### Override CSS class

You can override all `post` and `pre` tabs colors.

```css
/* import ./App.css */

/* first and last are red */
.ant-input-group-addon {
  background-color: red;
}

.ant-input-group-addon:first-child {
  background-color: purple;
}

.ant-input-group-addon:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

---

### Style your own component with Input.Group

Here we use [Input.Group](https://ant.design/components/input/) which groups components as done with `addonBefore` and `addonAfter`, you need to make your own `PreComponent` and `PostComponent` :

```js
<Input.Group compact>
  <PreComponent color="pink">{'http://'}<PreComponent/>
  <Input style={{ width: '30%' }} defaultValue="my site" />
  <PostComponent color="red">.com<PostComponent/>
</Input.Group>;
```

Check the demo to grasp what needs to be done:

[image: Edit Input Group Style]

Comment: Thank you, but I am actually floored ANTD does not have a better way to do this. How could they assume the post/pre items would not be themable? uggg.